# Add background-color or any css to "Section" in List Form in SharePoint Online using JSON formatting

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, json-formatting

We have provision to create *Sections* in Form body by putting in JSON code.

I also need to change `background-color` CSS property of the section.

[image]

```
{
    "sections": [
        {
            "displayname": " ",
            "fields": [
                "Reporting Period"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Schedule Management",
            "fields": [
                "EV",
                "PV"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Cost Management",
            "fields": [
                "AC",
                "CV"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Quality Management",
            "fields": [
                "Total NCRs raised",
                "No. of NCRs Open"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Procurement Management",
            "fields": [
                "Total Biomed Works"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Resource Management",
            "fields": [
                "Available Steel Rebar",
                "Required Steel Rebar",
                "Available Cement",
                "Required Cement",

            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Issues & Risk Management",
            "fields": [
                "Total Issues Reported",
                "Open Issues",
                "%OI"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "Health, Safety and Environemnt (HSE) Management",
            "fields": [
                "WTD HSE Score",
                "AR"
            ]
        },
        {
            "displayname": "General Process Audit",
            "fields": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Please how is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is **not supported** using JSON Formatting yet.

> Unlike the header and the footer, body configuration **only allows defining one or more sections** and adding one or more columns into each of those sections.

**Source**: [Configure custom body with one or more sections](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-configuration#configure-custom-body-with-one-or-more-sections)

Comment: What should we tell management? That we are working on it, or Microsoft is working on it... or we are simply incapable of working on SP & should be fired.. What's the best approach to handle such situation?

Comment: You can say that this is currently not supported by **Microsoft** (using JSON: easy/fast way). Alternatively, you can customize the form using Power Apps to design list form (which might take some time). IMO, customizing the form using Power Apps just for adding background color on form is not good choice - But again it depends on your requirements & it's your decision.